# can't use @user in form_for in rails 4 getting a nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that there are many questions a but every solution that i've tried did not work.
I am trying to create a sign in form, but I am getting the following error 
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

replacing `@user` with `User.new` will solve the error , but than I can't check for `@user.errors.any`..

any suggestions?

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset7">
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

      <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
          <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>


      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      <br>
      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my controller code is

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show]

  def new
        @user = User.new
  end

  # POST /user
  # POST /user.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /user/1
  # PATCH/PUT /user/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  # DELETE /user/1
  # DELETE /user/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
    end


end
```

Comment: Is the first bit of code your new view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your edit, update and delete actions, you do not set @user.
You should maybe change your before filter:

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

or

```
before_action :set_user, except: [:index, :new]
```